# Delete point in the text document and create a new file

Tags: java

I am trying to delete the points in my text document file, by replacing it with an empty string.

It does not work although the same works for the question mark.

**Sample:**

```
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
Stephensonstraße 07:10 07:40 08:13
... ... ...
Universitätsklinikum 04:36 05:06 05:39 06:25 06:57 07:27 07:57 08:27 08:57 11:57
... ... ... ... ...
Grönauer Baum 05:43 06:29 07:02 07:32 08:02 08:32 09:02 12:02
... ... ... ... ...
```

**Code**

```
private static void replace_word() {

    File file = new File("D:\\hl_sv\\L09MF.txt");
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("D:\\hl_sv\\L09MF2.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                writer.println(line.replace('?', '-'));
                writer.println(line.replace('.', ' '));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly "does not work"? what are you getting?

Comment: @sharonbn: I am getting a new file with the points as before but with hyphers?! I have tried to escape it but then I am getting the same.

Comment: @MrPencil why are there two println with replace method? You are writing each line two times - one with the dots, other one without dots. Works fine for me. With '?' you are looking to replace questionmark sign in the string.

Comment: You also mention "I am trying to delete the points in my text document file, by replacing it with an empty string." Empty string or space character? There is a big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing two versions of the same line to the output. One will have the "?" removed, but not the points. The other is vice versa. Your output will contain twice the number of lines as your input - was that your intention?

If you want the same output lines, with replaced "?" and ".", you should build an output line that contains all your conversions before writing:

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String outputLine = line.replace('?', '-');
outputLine = outputLine.replace('.', ' ');
writer.println(outputLine);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
writer.println(line.replace(/\.," "));
```

Comment: you probably meant "\\." as first arg.  however, Java Sring.replace() has a signature that accepts single char argments that are not regex interprated .